# Облачное хранилище для мобильного приложения. C#. Xamarin. Android. GitHub

Tags: c#, github, xamarin, xamarin.android, github-api

ВВЕДЕНИЕ: я пишу приложение для изучения слов(не коммерческое, для себя). Для его работы нужны словари(простые текстовые файлы). Я написал Desktop версию используя C# и Windows Forms и мобильную версию используя C# и Xamarin. Так вот я хотел бы чтобы была возможность синхронизировать эти словари между устройствами. Я решил использовать для этой цели GitHub, так как папка с словарями весит меньше 1 Мб.
ПРОБЛЕМА: я не нашел удобного способа обращаться к GitHub с Android устройства используя C# Xamarin. В случае с Windows Forms есть удобная библиотека LibGit2Sharp. Но, как я понял она не совместима с Xamarin. А другой библиотеки, которой можно было бы пользоваться для этих целей, я не нашел.

ВОПРОСЫ:

1. есть ли библиотека для обращения к GitHub с устройства Android совместимая с C# Xamarin, если нет, можно ли как-то иначе провернуть операцию загрузки и скачивания файла из публичного репозитория используя, например, System.Net.Http?
2. возможно я в принципе выбрал неправильный подход, и вы сможете порекомендовать мне какой-то другой способ для синхронизации словарей

Если у вас будут ко мне какие-то дополнительные вопросы - с удовольствием отвечу, так как сам в этом заинтересован. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Git - это не синхронизация настроек, а система версирования кода, не надо ее использовать для чего либо подобного. Вы сами написали "Облачное хранилище"  - таких куча, все крупные компании предоставляют подобные услуги (амазон, гугл, майкрософт, яндекс), только заплатите. Бесплатно, нет, вам не даст кто либо свой компьютер даром для хранения там чего либо, вы ведь не будете даром в своей квартире хранить чужие вещи, правильно? Ну а GitHub, тут как минимум каждому человеку нужен акк от гита, лично я закрыл бы ваше приложение при виде, что оно просит у меня данные от GitHub.

Comment: Ну и да [Сохранения Google Play](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames?hl=ru).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Извините, возможно не корректно выразился. 1) Я пишу это приложение исключительно для личного использования, поэтому проблема того что пользователю что-то не понравится исчезает. 2) Я хочу использовать GitHub, так как, как мне показалось, у него самый простой способ загрузки данных, так как не нужно подписывать никаких соглашений, получать лицензии и т.д. 3) Я знаю что GitHub используется для хранения и обмена кода, но также я прочитал, что там можно хранить файлы размером до 100 Мб, а моя папка весит меньше 1Мб, поэтому мне показалось что это будет хорошим решением

Comment: Если вы все для себя решили, то зачем тогда спрашиваете про правильность этого подхода? Вот я вам сказал, что считаю это плохим решением, вы ведь не послушаете меня, верно? В пет проектах вы вольны делать все, что хотите, это ваше право, поэтому хотите, делайте. Что касается библиотек, то они вам не нужны, достаточно стандартного C#. Смотрите документацию, ищите [нужный API](https://docs.github.com/ru/rest/repos/contents), отправляете этот запрос через `HttpClient`, готово.